# Django Simple History: Don't want to track User

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I'm working on a Django project, and I'd like to use Django Simple History to track changes to records. However, I'm facing an issue: I *don't* want to track the user who made the change (I'm not using Django's auth app).

When I try to perform the migrations, I receive this error message:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
my_app.HistoricalModel.history_user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model
 'auth.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
data_lake.HistoricalInstance.history_user: (fields.E307) 
The field my_app.HistoricalInstance.history_user was declared with a lazy reference to 
'auth.user', but app 'auth' isn't installed.
```

Is there a way to use the `HistoricalRecords` model disabling references to user model?

Answer (score 0):

There are mentioning it in the documentation [here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_tracking.html#manually-track-user-model-1)

There are three parameters to `HistoricalRecords` or `register` that facilitate the ability to track a `history_user` manually:
`history_user_id_field`, `history_user_getter`, `history_user_setter`.

In your case, you might want to change the model of the user, you can do it when defining `HistoricalRecords` as well:

```
def set_historical_user_none(historical_instance, user):
    historical_instance.history_user_id = None

class MyModal(models.Model):
   history = HistoricalRecords(
                 user_model={django_model}, 
                 history_user_setter=set_historical_user_none)
```

Comment: I'd like to set it to `None`... I'll try that

Comment: I updated the answer to support that - but you have to give one of the existing django models afaik

Comment: It can be *any* Django model, right? If this is it, I can create an empty model as a place holders for this! Let me try